# How to check if a specific value exists in table column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have 2 tables in a database and they have a foreign key relation thru the column called id. 
So I have the id (representing a user and is the primary key in the user table) from one table and want to check weather that user has existing data in the other table.

So I wish to run the id against the column called id in the other table and if the id exists in that column return value true.
I´m not getting any error at the moment but the method does not return any value. So I must be doing something wrong... Any help appreciated!

This is the class and  method I have in one file:

```
class test {

    public function dataExists ()
        {
            $db = Database::getInstance();
            $classUser = new user();
            $userId = $classUser->getUserData($_SESSION['id']);
            $user = $userId['id'];

            $query = $db->prepare("`id` SELECT * FROM `data`");

            if ($user == $query)
            {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
}
```

And the in my view file I have this:

```
$classTest = new test();
$exists = $classTest->dataExists();

if ($exists == true) {

echo '';

}
```

Comment: you do realise that right now you're comparing two different objects?

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are checking if a [`mysqli_stmt`](http://php.net/manual/class.mysqli-stmt.php) object (returned from [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.prepare.php)) equals a number. How do you think this comparison should work?

You can do this via `num_rows`, this is taken pretty straight forward from [the manual](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)

```
public function dataExists () {
    //...
    if ($statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `id`=?")) {
        $statement->bind_param("i", $user);
        $statement->execute();
        //...
        return ($statement->num_rows > 0);
    }
}
```

Since you are working with classes, you might want to store the results of the query somewhere - asking for their existence implies that you might want to use them.

I shortened the `return` statement as

```
if ($a==$b) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

is equal to

```
return ($a==$b);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see what you mean but I don´t follow with the return statement... If the user has existing data matching the id I need to return true else false. Should I use this return ($statement->num_rows > 0); or not?

Comment: Also I´m using PDO instead of mysqli!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to figure it out with PDO using fetchAll() and count() and then comparing results similar to your answer.

Comment: That is what I meant with the last paragraph. `num_rows > 0` is a comparison, so it is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. When working with comparisons you can return them directly and you will get the same as result as if you used `if(num_rows > 0) {return TRUE;} else {return FALSE;}`

Comment: This looks alot like ORM (although not knowing your intents/the rest of the code it is hard to tell) - maybe you should research how this topic has been approached before. I think all major PHP frameworks provide them in one way or another

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the query statement

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `data` where `id` = ?
```

and then just test for the value returned.

This has the benefit of only returning the number of records that match your query rather than matching and returning all the records that do. While that may be okay for a small number of records if your second table has 50,000 records that match you probably don't want to pull all of them just to find out that there are 50,000 of them!